# SFML getting user input in window loop

Tags: c++, sfml

I did a program (cpu scheduler ) with sf::Clock which gets data from file  then calculates waiting time and turn around time and draws rectangle in window every second to show how processes are served. But now I need to add an option to also get data from user when the program is working ( drawing rectangles ) and I have no idea how to do it. I'm opening file and writing in it and after closing it I'm drawing rectangles. All of this is in window loop. So I thought that maybe after throwing out of window loop code with file handling and then getting input from user will help, but the drawing rectangles code doesn't know variables and i can' t throw it out of window loop because it draws. Then I thought that maybe I should do getting input from user (std::cin) in window loop for example after pressing some keyboard key, but it was going to infinity, all time asking for input to this same variables. Is it possible to do what I want ?

Comment: Show us some code?

Comment: @Mario Done! Part of my code.

Comment: Ideally a more minimal code sample that compiles but still demonstrates the problem

Comment: @Carl now it should compile i add essential things from main.

Comment: @Carl There is no problem stated; the OP just seems to want suggestions on how to do something new. The one indication of a problem was an infinite loop with `cin`, but they didn't include that code here. There is no clear question to answer.

Comment: @underscore_d the loop was only something like: std::cout<<"write number of process"; std::cin>>proc[lp]; ( lp is variable of lines in file) and same cout and cin for wait time and turnaround time. But you know this loop went to infinity, because of window.open()

Comment: Which kind of data will you receive from user?(window clicks, text input..)

Comment: I want numbers. Number of process, wait time and turnaround time. These data are in file, now i have a file with only 3 processes and I want to let user add more when program is running ( program is drawing rectangles ).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].